# `add_set_reserved_peer` with Unknown Protocol

Tags: beefy, gossip

I have just integrated BEEFY into my runtime.
A single node works well.
But it can not gossip.

```
add_set_reserved_peer with unknown protocol: /paritytech/beefy/1
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this config into service.rs.

```
config
    .network
    .extra_sets
    .push(beefy_gadget::beefy_peers_set_config());
```